# Move Gnome 3 hot corner

Tags: gnome, desktop

I just added a 2nd monitor to the LEFT of my laptop, keeping my laptop screen as primary. The problem is that the hot corner in Gnome that switches to activities is now in the middle, making it hard to hit.  I want to move it to the top right or bottom right.  I found that a lot of Gnome is powered by js, and this file:

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js
```

Has:

```
this._hotCorner = new Layout.HotCorner();
container.add_actor(this._hotCorner.actor);
```

But this just enables and disables it I can't seem to find a way to move it.

Answer (score 1):

In my current Ubuntu `14.04`, Gnome `3.10.4`, the hot corners are created in the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/layout.js`.

Look for `_updateHotCorners:` - it's a function that computes the hot corners. In my case I wanted to enable the hot corner on the external monitor as well so I just commented out the two `haveTopLeftCorner = false` in the inner `for` loop.

Then just `Alt+F2` and `r` to restart Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you some control, but unfortunately doesn't currently handle multiple monitors very nicely.  I added an issue feature request.
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/309/hot-corn-dog/